# Making a heat map out of a two dimensional array of ints in python

Tags: python, heatmap

I have an array called defined as:

`heatmap = [[0 for y in range(h)] for range x in range (w)]`

which contains only integers.

I'd like to know how, if there is any way at all, to turn this two dimensional array of ints into a heat map similar to the one you can find [here](http://webtoolsandtips.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/12/heatmap.jpg).

Sorry if this is vague, I'm at school right now, but I will try to answer any questions as fast as possible

Comment: A 2-dimensional array only has enough information to have x and y coordinates, it doesn't contain a "heat" value to display at the location. How are you planning on getting that?

Comment: @Chachmu - I just made an edit to the code I showed which may explain the confusion, though I'm not sure. Basically this array allows me to call for: `heatmap[0][6]` and have whatever that has been previously set to in response. That works and I've tested it (using python by the way). Now I'd like to find out a way to generate a heat map with those "heat" values.